# I have some code that I would llike to make shorter

Tags: linq

I have these two bits of code where I have a list highAmtCtrList which is a list that I get from ddr.Out.
It's a list of contracts where you can have two records with the same contract number.

I use highAmtCtrList to get all first records only.

Then within a foreach, I check if the contracts in ddr.Dil match those of highAmtCtrList. If they do, I update the amount in highAmtCtrList with that of ddr.Dil.

The code I have works, it's just that I've been trying to turn it into one bit of code and can't seem to get around it.

Any ideas??
Tks in advance.
Rui Martins

```
List<Outstanding> highAmtCtrList =

                            (from d in ddr.Out
                             group d by d.Contract
                                 into g
                                 let highestInstallment =
                                     (from x in g
                                      orderby x.Amount descending
                                      select x).First()

                                 select highestInstallment).ToList();


highAmtCtrList.ForEach(outs => outs.Amount += ddr.Dil
   .Where(dil => dil.Contract == outs.Contract) 
   .Select(dil => dil.Amount) 
   .FirstOrDefault()); 

          }
```

Comment: "I've been trying to turn it into one bit of code" Why? Can you show all the properties in the type `Outstanding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it on my own. I merged the two lists